# Cutting off decimal point

Tags: java, calculator

How would I format this so it shows no decimal points after the Miles per hour has been calculated? I have no idea how to format this at all. What I am currently getting is that it is rounding but it leaves a `.0` after and it just doesn't look right. I also have to keep it as a `double`.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MilesPerHour {
  private int distance, hours, minutes;
  private double mph;

  public MilesPerHour() {
    setNums(0,0,0);
    mph = 0;
  }

  public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins) {
    distance = dist;
    hours = hrs;
    minutes = mins;
  }

  public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins) {

  }

  public void calcMPH() {
    mph = Math.round((distance)/(hours + (minutes/60)));
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.print(distance + " miles in " + hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes = " + mph + " MPH.");
  } 

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);
    out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
    int dist = keyboard.nextInt();
    out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
    int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

    out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
    int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

    MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins);
    test.calcMPH();
    test.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: double will show .0 when converted to string. So, you can cast it as int `System.out.print(distance + " miles in " + hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes = " + ((int)mph) + " MPH.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String.format()` to display your double rounded as an integer:

```
System.out.println("My number: " + String.format("%.0f", 2.5d));
```

will display `My number: 3`.

Refer to the [full documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for the syntax of the String formatter.

Comment: You can use this, or if you want, you could use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: Maybe he uses `Math.round()` for the value, not just when displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
private double mph;
```

`mph` will remain `double` even you assigned `Math.round()`'s return value to it. And when you invoke `System.out.print()`, `mph` got referenced as a `double`, resulting in the trailing ".0".

Simply add a type cast like this will do:

```
System.out.print(" MPH: " + ((int)mph) );
```